# C#, Lambda to transfer elements from one list to another

Tags: c#, lambda

Is there a simple lambda expression to extract elements from one list and put them into another? without LINQ?

for example to map, a source list of elements T to another list (or return a list) with the string name for each element in the source.

Update...with pseudocode.

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3};         
List<string> stringList = new List<string>(intList.ToArray((i) => intList[i].ToString())); // this doesn't work obviously
```

stringList should be {"1", "2", "3"}

Comment: Can you clarify your desired input and outputs with some specific examples? It'd be good if you could also post any code you've already tried!

Comment: What's wrong with LINQ, anyway?

Comment: I agree LINQ is the way to go, but maybe he is stuck on .NET 2.0 for some reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`List<T>.ConvertAll()` provides a straightforward way to change types without LINQ.

In your case...

```
List<string> stringList = intList.ConvertAll(i => i.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I wanted.